# i can not get Ubuntu to install on my laptop

Tags: flash

When I try to load Ubuntu from a flash drive it does not find the boot-able drive.  I have tried a disk and it works, but I want to boot from my flash drive.

Comment: You haven't provided too much information. What model is your laptop?  Are you trying to create a bootable flash drive to install to your laptop? Or are you trying to create a persistent installation on the flash drive itself?

Comment: In all likelihood your BIOS is simply missing flash drives in its boot order. Can you check it out?

Answer (score 0):

How did you make the USB? It sounds like the USB wasn't tagged as bootable, but that doesn't explain why it doesn't show up in your bootmenu.

Check your BIOS to see if USB booting is enabled.

Does your USB have a LED? Is it coming on when your computer boots up? If not, try setting a delay in your POST.